# Shift whitespace

Tags: awk, sed

Consider this file

```
$ cat infile.txt
  1111
    2222
      3333
  4444
```

Notice carefully that each line has at least 2 leading spaces. I would like to
shift all the lines evenly left, until at least one line has no leading spaces,
example

```
$ cat outfile.txt
1111
  2222
    3333
4444
```

Now in this case that would mean shifting everything left 2 spaces, but the
solution would need to work with other files that might need more or less
shifting. Please use awk or sed for this task if possible. I tried this

```
awk '(sub("  ",""))' infile.txt
```

But it will not work if a line initially has less than 2 spaces.

Comment: Does the first line always have the minimum amount of initial whitespace? Or do you have to search the whole file to find that?

Comment: I noticed in your expected results.. the lines have more than one leading spaces..is this correct? since you want lines with no leading  spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'H;$!d;x;:a;/\n+\S/!s/(\n+) /\1/g;ta;s/.//' file
```

Kudos to NeronLeVelu, I just tidied up his solution.

Comment: no prob, your variation suite me perfectly and use the features of GNU sed too keep it "simple"

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk -F"[^ ]" '!NF {next} {s=length($1);a[NR]=$0} min>s||NR==1 {min=s} END {for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) print substr(a[i],min+1)}' file
1111
  2222
    3333
4444
```

It does count the spaces in front of first characters, then find the lowest number.
Using this, then strip of spaces in front of text.

---

Some more readable:

```
awk -F"[^ ]" '
!NF {next}
    {s=length($1)
    a[NR]=$0}
min>s||NR==1 {
    min=s}
END {
    for (i=1;i<=NR;i++)
        print substr(a[i],min+1)}
' file
```

---

By setting field separator to `"[^ ]"` (not space), the first field will contain the space group.
This way `length($1)` gives number of spaces in front of text, regardless if there are more spaces within the text or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '#n
H;${x
:cycle
   h
:nld
   s/\(\n\)\1/\1 \1/g;t nld
   s/\(n\)$/\1 /

   /\n[^ ]/ !{
      s/\(\n\)[ ]/\1/g
      b cycle
      }
   x
   s/.//p
   }' YourFile
```

- Autoadaptive to number of space BUT don't take care of empty (or only space) line
- <strike>Assume `³` is not used (used as delimiter but another character could be used).</strike>
- is not efficient on huge file (load the file in memory buffer twice and multiple replace recursively)

*Thanks to @potong for all the usefull remarks about different bugs or simply algorythm*

Comment: special char are touchy on posix version (I use an AIX sed) so Hexa, Octa and decimal definition of char and sometimes traditional `\n` does not work. On GNU sed, it will be easier with use of pattern like `[^ \n]`

Comment: As is this solution returns the wrong result. Perhaps the `-n` switch has been forgotton or the last command should be `;d`. Also I believe there is no need for the `³` character if you reconsider the substitution commands (this will remove another bug that has been introduced i.e. what happens when 3 newlines are in a row?). Lastly `H` inserts a newline and then appends the patten buffer, consider the first line?

Comment: right, i forget the -n (correction in post thanks) and other remarks,  focused on the problem of starting space. Thank for this and sorry for poor coding.

Answer (score 1):

Another (G)awk

Read file twice(low memory)

```
awk '{a=(x=match($0,/[^ ]/))<a||!a?x:a}FNR!=NR{print substr($0,a)}' file{,}
```

Checks when the first none space is and stores it.
Then on the second file prints a substr of the line starting at the lowest value stored.

Read file once(with large amount of memory used)

```
 awk '{a=(x=match(b[NR]=$0,/[^ ]/))<a||!a?x:a}END{while(++i<=NR)print substr(b[i],a)}' file
```

Same as the first one except each line is stored in an array and a substring is of each line in the array is printed.

#### example

`input`

```
  1111 1111
    2222 2222
      3333 3333
  4444 4444
```

`output`

```
1111 1111
  2222 2222
    3333 3333
4444 4444
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

in a script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;

my $len;

while (<>) {
    if ($. == 1) {
        (my $spaces = $_ ) =~ s/^(\s+).*/$1/;
        $len = (length $spaces) - 1;
    }
    print substr $_, $len;
}
```

or in command line :

```
$ perl -ne '
    $. == 1 and do{
        (my $spaces = $_ ) =~ s/^(\s+).*/$1/;
        $len = (length $spaces) - 1;
    };
    print substr $_, $len
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you need to have a shift left **multiple of 2 white spaces**.

I tried to make it as short and simple as possible using sed and shell:

```
#while there is no line beginning with 0 spaces
while ! grep "^ \?[^ ]" infile.txt > /dev/null; do 
    #on each line of the file remove the first spaces
    sed -i "s/^  //"  infile.txt ;
done
```

Note 1:
grep instruction does not match empty lines. So empty lines are not considered as not shifted lines.

You may want the grep to match empty lines : "^ \?[^ ]\|^$"

Note 2:
Empty files, would make while loop infinite.
You may want to use grep -v "^  ", in this case: empty lines are considered as not shifted.

Mind that you can create a copy of the infile.txt instead of working on it.

I'm sure it is possible to traduce the while loop and the grep into some sed instructions. But you would have to concatenate all lines in the sed buffer which is not it's nominal use.

Answer (score 0):

One way, using AWK:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {
    x = length($0)
    sub(/^ */, "")
    y = x - length($0)
    if (r > y || NR==1) r = y
    next
}{
    print substr($0, r + 1)
}' infile.txt{,}
```

This solution reads the input file twice:

- On the first read, determine the largest allowable indentation level
- On the second read, print the line at the determined offset

Comment: Not sure if it would matter but just a note that this would fail if there were more than 1 field.

Comment: @Jidder: Easily fixed. See [these](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27619204/revisions) edits for a shorter solution if the input file contains a single column.